# How to make "AM/PM" appear in the minutes dropdown in Rails' datetime_select method? Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to make the "AM/PM" that is displayed in the Rails `datetime_select` method (when `:ampm => true` is active), or even a way to separate it into its own dropdown box? [Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-datetime_select) for the `datetime_select` method is scarce beyond what I linked and nothing seems to address this issue.

Can it be done? Preferably without the use of any JavaScript?

This is what I get when I state this:

```
<%= f.datetime_select :when, { :ampm  => true, :minute_step => 10 }, :class => "form-control" %>
```

[image: The default <code>datetime_select</code> method with <code>:ampm => true</code>]